# Populate a String array with text file stored on sdcard

Tags: android

I have a text file on my sdcard filled like this :

test1

test2

test3

I would like to populate a String array by reading the file and get an array like this :

`String[] val = {"test0","test1","test2"};`

This is how I read the file but how can I read each line and fill the array ? :

```
 public void ReadSettings(){

    try{             
           File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/file.txt");             
           FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);          
           BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));           
           String readString = new String();                

           while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {

               Log.d("line: ", readString);   

           for (int i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
                      val[i] = readString;

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {          
           e.printStackTrace();          
        } catch (IOException e){             
           e.printStackTrace();          
    }    
}
```

This is what I get unfortunetly :

`String[] val = {"test2","test2","test2"};`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("line: ", readString);   
    val[i++] = readString;
    // u better use an ArrayList or you have to check if i < val.size
}
```